# Как правильно обрабатывать объекты json c помощью json.Parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

Имею такой код на HTML странице:

```
....
ws.onmessage=function(e){
    temp = JSON.parse(e.data);};
...
```

Периодически на страницу поступают json данные. Пример данных: {"r":1,"s":1}, {"r":5,"s":0}, {"temp_air":"25 °C"}, {"humi_air":"50 %"} и т.п.
Когда поступает строка вида {"r":5,"s":0} требуется выполнять функцию установки или удаления атрибута объектов на странице, где relay_id это значение ключа r, а status это значение ключа s.

```
function changeStateRelay(relay_id, status) {
    if (status == 1) {
        document.querySelector('#relay'+relay_id).setAttribute("checked", "checked");}
    if (status == 0) {
        document.querySelector('#relay'+relay_id).removeAttribute("checked");}
}
```

а когда поступает строка вида {"humi_air":"50 %"} требуется подставить значение в определенные поля используя document.getElementById(key).innerText = value;
, где key это ключ temp_air или humi_air или другого, а value это значение этих ключей.

Когда данные были только вида {"r":1,"s":1},..,{"r":5,"s":0} я использовал код который замечательно работал:

```
ws.onmessage=function(e){
    temp = JSON.parse(e.data);
    changeStateRelay(temp.r, temp.s);
    }
function changeStateRelay(relay_id, status) {
    if (status == 1) {
        document.querySelector('#relay'+relay_id).setAttribute("checked", "checked");}
    if (status == 0) {
        document.querySelector('#relay'+relay_id).removeAttribute("checked");}
}
```

для данных вида {"temp_air":"25 °C"},..., {"humi_air":"50 %"} я начал использовать код:

```
ws.onmessage=function(e){
    temp = JSON.parse(e.data, function(key, value){
            document.getElementById(key).innerText = value});
}
```

Как объединить эти два способа в один?

Comment: Данные вы получаете со стороннего сервиса или генерируете у себе на бэкенде?

Comment: Данные генерирую сам. Я понимаю, что я могу генерировать данные вида {"r":9,"s":50 %} где я для себя приму, что "r"=9 будет соответствовать "temp_air" и соответствующим образом обрабатывать, однако хотелось бы понять как можно парсить разнотипные данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Желательно генерировать данные с указанием типа например

```
{
    "type": "type_first",
    "data": {...}
 }
```

После получения обрабатывать их уже в соответствии с указанным типом, например:

```
if(response.type == 'type_first') 
    typeFirstHandler(response.data)
else if(response.type == 'type_second') 
    typeSecondHandler(response.data)
```

То есть для каждого типа данных пишите обработчик, такой подход избавит вас от проблем когда понадобится расширить функционал обработки ответа.

Также можно не указывать тип и обрабатывать "чистые" данные, например

```
let temp = JSON.parse(response)
if (typeof temp[0]['r'] != "undefined"){ // если в первом объекте массива есть ключ 'r'
    // ....
} else if(typeof temp[0]['temp_air'] != "undefined") { // если в первом объекте массива есть ключ 'temp_air'
    // ....
}
```

Второй способ крайне не желателен т.к вся логика обработки данных в одном месте и когда вам придется расширить функционал или что-то переписать то вы столкнетесь с кучей самых различных проблем.

Также к слову на бэкенде в ответе лучше задать заголовок `Content-Type: application/json` тогда не придется писать `JSON.parse(...)`, данные сразу придут в виде объекта а не строки.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий! Уже сам склоняюсь к единообразию генерируемых данных вида {"r":"first_type","s":"data"}.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, поставьте галочку.